# select from multiple columns: codeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I want to select multiple columns in a table using codeIgniter active records. Selecting using

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table_name);
```

but selecting a number of columns e.g.

```
   $this->db->select('username','email','last_login','created','modified','group_id');
    $this->db->from($this->table_name);
```

does not work.It only returns an array with the values from the first column. How should I do this?

according to the CodeIgniter user guide they gave the following example. so I thought it should work in my case.

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');

$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

// Produces: SELECT title, content, date FROM mytable
```

Comment: As Wesley shows, there are a few practices from MYSQL that you need to forget when using Active Records. You can also simply use $this->db->from('table_name'); or $this->db->get('table_name'); without the $this->

Comment: Not sure what Brad's talking about, but you can indeed use [method chaining](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#chaining) as many AR calls like `select` and `where` return the AR object. As far as normal SQL syntax goes, you can always use it. The second example of yours is not in SQL syntax, while the one I provided, which works with AR, is also correct (partial) SQL syntax. Besides that you can use `$this->db->query()` to run any normal SQL query. I suggest you pay no mind to the above comment, it's very misleading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second query will not work as you expect, as `select()` expects a string or array as the first parameter rather than taking unlimited arguments. In your example, only `username` would be selected. The correct **string** syntax is this:

```
$this->db->select('username, email, last_login, created, modified, group_id');
```

There's much more I could share with you, but I suggest you have another read or two through the [Active Record documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) instead. Good luck, and enjoy Codeigniter!

**AFTER YOUR EDIT**: Please note the differences in these two examples:

**1** - This line passes each column as a separate argument:

```
$this->db
    ->select('username','email','last_login','created','modified','group_id');
```

**2** - This line correctly passes **one** argument (comma separated string):

```
$this->db
    ->select('username, email, last_login, created, modified, group_id');
```

Note the absence of quotes around each column name in the (correct) example **2**. In example 1, there are several arguments passed to the function, and only the first one is used, while the rest are ignored.

Comment: I have edited the question and added an example from codeIgniter user guide. So I thought it should work in my case as well.

Comment: @serengeti12: The difference is that in your first example, you pass several arguments to `select()`, and in the second example you only pass one argument: a comma separated string. Do you see the difference?

Comment: ooh..my bad..I see the difference now. I  guess I should be more careful next time.