# Ajax Auto-complete search with Code-igniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Ajax Auto-complete search with Code-igniter from my database. I am trying to search my database and Ajax completes the search from items saved on my database. I believe I am missing a simple trick. Maybe I am writing my controller or maybe everything all wrong... Code below

// View Page
Location path: application/views/template/header

```
<form class="navbar-form" >
                        <input type="text" id="mysearch" placeholder="search" onkeyup="doSearch();">                        
                        <br />
```

```
<script>

   // This is the jQuery Ajax call
   function doSearch()
   {
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url:"localhost/codeigniter/index.php/ajax/getdata/" + $("#mysearch").val(),
         success:function(result){
         $("#searchresults").html(result);
      }});
   }
   //class example



</script>

Note: My form or search box is inside my header... So my view page is located in template/header

// Controller Page

Location path: codeigniter/application/controller/ajax.php

class Ajax extends CI_Controller 
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('ajax_model');
                //$this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function form ()
        {
            $data['title'] = 'Ajax search';

            $this->load->view('template/header');
        }


        // function ends

    public function getdata($param = '')
   {
      // Get data from db 
      $data['ajaxdata'] = $this->ajax_model->search($param);

      // Pass data to view
     $this->load->view('template/header', $data);


   }

}

?>
```

// My Model
   Location path: application/model/Ajax_model.php

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access');

class Ajax_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }

    public function search ($title){
        $this->db->select('title');
        $this->db->select('text');
        $this->db->like('title', $title, 'both');
        return $this->db->get('news');
    }

}

?>
```

Please be aware I am new to CodeIgniter. It explains my rather obvious ignorance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data['ajaxdata'] = $this->ajax_model->search($param);
$data['ajaxdata'] = json_encode($data['ajaxdata']);

echo $data['ajaxdata'];
```

Ajax method expects data in form of (JSON) string. So you don't need to load header again. Instead, just pass needed data from DB and jQuery will put it in designated place. In this case into element with id of searchresults.

Comment: tried your suggestion and it did make a difference to my result . Thanks but not returning data from my database yet instead I get this  {"conn_id":{"affected_rows":null,"client_info":null,"client_version":null,"connect_errno":null,"connect_error":null,"errno":null,"error":null,"field_count":null,"host_info":null,"info":null,"insert_id":null,"server_info":null,"server_version":null,"stat":null,"sqlstate":null,"protocol_version":null,"thread_id":null,"warning_count":null},"result_id":

Comment: Similar to query without get method. Try this though: remove one select line and use this `$this->db->select('title, text');`. Can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112972/select-from-multiple-columns-codeigniter#answer-6117454) too.

Comment: instead of as suggested "echo $data['ajaxdata'];" if I include "$this->load->view('ajax/index', $data);" in my controller and try to format result in my index.php view page with my $ajaxdata. How do I put that in a loop? I have been trying to work it out and tried a for loop but again I may be missing something

Comment: Why would you export view file if you use ajax to get certain data?

Comment: Because I want it displayed with styling. I am not sure if I can do it differently because I am new with it all

Comment: Make styling in javascript after getting wanted data.

Comment: I want it displayed with styling. I am not sure if I can do it differently because I am new with it all because the data I output doesn't have any styling to it. It comes out like this [{"title":"Single","text":"A room assigned to one person. May have one or more beds."},{"title":"Exquisite","text":"Lovely pool view double bed room"},{"title":"Cousy","text":"A very comfortable luxury double bed room"}]

Comment: Other way to return already formatted string is to make it in controller already. Instead loading view you have to make string that would correspond wanted html output and than `echo "<div class=\"some-class\">$some_var_from_db</div>";`. Probably you should use foreach and make it accordingly. But main thing need to be understood is ajax expects `echo "something";` from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
$this->load->view('template/header', $data);
```

to

```
$content = $this->load->view('template/header', $data,TRUE);
// load view to a variable.
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am clear what you need try:
first define ajax request type:

```
function doSearch()
   {
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         dataType:"html",
         url:"localhost/codeigniter/index.php/ajax/getdata/" + $("#mysearch").val(),
         success:function(result){
         $("#searchresults").html(result);
      }});
   }
```

> Then in controller :

just echo your view:

```
$auto_complete_html = $this->load->view('template/header', $data,TRUE);
echo $auto_complete_html;
//good practice always die(); after ajax called 
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using POST in AJAX instead of GET:

```
<script>

   // This is the jQuery Ajax call
   function doSearch()
   {
      var search = $("#mysearch").val()
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"localhost/codeigniter/ajax/getdata/",
         data:'search=' + search,
         success:function(data){
         $("#searchresults").html(data);
      }});
   }
   //class example

</script>
```

Then in your controller Get THE POSTED data from AJAX

```
    public function getdata()
   {
$param= $this->input->post('search');
      // Get data from db 
     $result = $this->ajax_model->search($param);

      // Pass data to view
 echo $result; 


   }
```