# autosuggestion textbox in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a database with name 'client_details' wherein i want to pull column 'client_name' and show it in textbox for autosuggestion while user is typing.
*I went through all internet sites but still no success*

For Simplicity i have kept all code separate. I have created a separate custom.js file to do the autocomplete work and loaded it through the 'admin_footer.php'

**here is my View 'home_admin_view'**

```html
<?php include('admin_header.php');?>

<div class="container">
 <?php echo form_open('Home_controller/search',['class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'search']);?>
 <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">-->
     <div class="col-lg-2">
     </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
          <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
        </div>
         <div class="col-lg-1">
        <button type="submit" id="name_search" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
     </div>
      <?= form_close(); ?>
      <?= form_error('query',"<p class='navbar-text text-danger'>", '</p>')?>
</div>

<?php include('admin_footer.php');?>
```

**Controller 'Client_controller'**

```html
<?php
class Client_controller extends MY_Controller{

 public function index()
 { 
   $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->view('home_admin_view');

 }

 public function search_client()
 { 
      if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->client_model->search($q);
           }
      }
  }
?>
```

**Model 'client_model'**

```html
<?php
class Client_model extends CI_Model{

 public function search($q)
 {
   $this->db->select('client_name');
      $this->db->like('client_name', $q);
      $query = $this->db->get('client_details');
      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
          $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['client_name'])); //build an array
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
      }
 }
}
?>
```

and Finally my custom.js file which i have declared in the footer of the home_admin_view

```js
/*******************Customer Search********************/  
    /*To Get Name*/
    $("#client_name").autocomplete({
        source: "Client_controller/search_client"      
    });
   


    /* To Get Client Complete details*/   
    $('#name_search').click(function() {
        var name=$("#client_name").val();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "Client_controller/search_client",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',   
            data: ({
                'client_name': client_name
            }),
            success: function(data){   
                try{    
                   //Code to pull complete Client data
                }catch(e) {  
                    alert('Client does not exists!'); 
                }  
            } 
        });  
    });
```

ill post my 'Home_Controller' just in case if required

```html
<?php
class Home_controller extends MY_Controller{

 public function index()
 { 
   $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->view('home_admin_view');

 }

 public function search()
 {
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('query','Client Name','required');
      if(!$this->form_validation->run())
       $this->index();
     // $query=$this->input->post('query');
      
      //print_r($query);
      
      }
  }
?>
```

But Some how it is Not pulling any data for autosuggestion in the textbox, i am new to this but still have enough knowledge . Please help , i am stuck and i need to finish this as early as possible.

Your kind help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You may visit this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215301/ajax-auto-complete-search-with-code-igniter)

Comment: Tried that ...no Success yet :(

Comment: Did you check request and response in console?

Comment: `$query = $this->db->get('client_details');` echo the raw query for the given query and fire it on mysql terminal and see if it return some value or not ?

Comment: @Ruturaj You are passing `$_GET['term']` in your `public function search_client()
 { 
      if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->client_model->search($q);
           }
      }` function please try to get what value that you have in it

Comment: ill check n let u know

Comment: $query = $this->db->get('client_details'); returns me raw data, so my mysql data flow works fine, i guess issue must be with (isset($_GET['term'])) cannot figue out whether it gets data or not to check the condition also having doubt on my model code

Comment: Anyone with any solution??

Answer (score 0):

**Guys Finallyyyyy ,we found the Solution... It works perfectly fine. My friend helped me to fix the issue**

**The issue was with the .JS and .CSS files which i was calling through admin_header.php and admin_footer.php**

**Include following lines of code to user admin_eader.php (Provided i assume u have alredy downloaded these files in ur assets folder OR you can give CDN links)**

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Fire Prevention</title> 
  
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template --> 
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/jquery-ui.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet"/>  

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js') ?>" ></script> 

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 </head>
```

and This code in your admin_footer.php

```html
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
    <!--  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script> 
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js') ?> "></script>
    <!-- JQuery UI Javascript--> 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-ui.js') ?> "></script> 
    <!-- JQuery Datepicker Javascript--> 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') ?> "></script> 
    <!-- Custom Javascript--> 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/custom.js') ?> "></script> 
 </body>
```

And try to load .js files in footer might be a good practice...it loads pages faster...Thanks and Enjoy!!